# Activate a sheet in excel 2010 vba using a variable name

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to activate a sheet using a variable name and am getting a subscript out of range error

the variable is declared this way

**`Phonecall = Phones(i) & "-UnbilledData"`**

when i is 1, Phonecall's value is "999-9999-UnbilledData"

This statement fails with the subscript error

**`Sheets(Phonecall).Activate`**

This statement works fine:

**`sheets("999-9999-UnbilledData").activate`**

The solution is staring me in the face, but I'm not seeing it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you *sure* Phones(1) contains exactly what you think it does?  Cause when I do similar, it works as expected. See here at PasteBin for the code I tried: http://pastebin.com/yv9NGj3x

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue turned out to be getting sheet names confused with workbook names, so the question is unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted any **Dim**'s  The following works just fine:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim Phones(1 To 2) As String
   Phones(1) = "999-9999"
   Phones(2) = "whatever"
   Dim Phonecall As String
   i = 1
   Phonecall = Phones(i) & "-UnbilledData"
   Sheets(Phonecall).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: My findings as well.  Perhaps OP has some unexpected whitespace in his array?

Comment: Thanks, guys,
The issue turns out to be getting sheet names confused with workbook names ( the workbook name is the one with extension name)

Each phone had it's own workbook and each workbook had one sheet

This is the code that ultimately worked for me:
 
        Dim Phones(1 To 2) As String
        Phones(1) = "999-9999"
        Phones(2) = "888-8888"

        For i = 1 To 2
             phonecall = Phones(i) & "-UnbilledData.xls"
             Windows(phonecall).Activate
            Sheets(1).Activate
            Sheets(1).Move After:=Workbooks("Current.xls").Sheets(i)
        Next